# Using IN operator in Subquery with Group By

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, ora-00913

I'm having some trouble with a query. I'm supposed to pull up all the client info where the client has only taken 1 test and passed. I was told to use the `IN` operator. This is what I have:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Client
 WHERE ClientName IN (SELECT ClientName, COUNT(TestNbr)
                        FROM Test
                    GROUP BY ClientName, TestResult
                      HAVING COUNT(TestNbr)=1
                         AND TestResult='Pass');
```

I get this error:

```
(SELECT ClientName, COUNT(TestNbr)
 *
ERROR at line 4: 
ORA-00913: too many values
```

I understand that it's because I shouldn't have any other entry except for ClientName in that line. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the `COUNT(*)` column on the subquery as it is not neccesary on the result,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Client
WHERE   ClientName IN
        (
            SELECT  ClientName
            FROM    Test
            GROUP   BY ClientName, TestResult
            HAVING  COUNT(TestNbr) = 1 AND TestResult='Pass'
        );
```

but I'd rather use `JOIN` instead of using `IN`

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    Client a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  ClientName
            FROM    Test
            GROUP   BY ClientName, TestResult
            HAVING  COUNT(TestNbr) = 1 AND TestResult='Pass'
        ) b ON a.ClientName = b.ClientName
```

for faster performance, add an index on column `ClientName` on both tables.

Comment: Not sure I buy the inline view here as you're not using any fields from it. Also I think I would move the `testresult='Pass'` from the `having` put it in the `where` and remove testresult from the `group by`

Comment: I agree with Conrad -- `HAVING` is for aggregate function use.  It supports non-aggregate functionality, doesn't mean it should be used.

Answer (score 2):

An `IN` clause can only contain one column if a sub-query is used. You should remove the `COUNT` from the columns selected if it's a problem.

What you might want to do is make a `VIEW` that represents the sub-query and then `JOIN` against that.

Comment: There's no benefit to making a non-materialized view.  If anything, the encapsulation is bad and predicate pushing might not occur.

Comment: I've always preferred `SELECT ClientName FROM ClientsWithPassingTestResults` to `SELECT ClientName FROM...` and a considerable mess of SQL. Maybe it's just me.